# Problema el background de un input cambia de color cuando selecciono el usuario ya guardado en la cache

Tags: html, css, input

Tengo un problema con el input de tipo Text y esque cuando selecciono el usuario ya guardado en la cache cambia de color a blanco y no respeta el que yo le di eso solo pasa cuando lo selecciono con el mouse o la flecha down la sugerencia que da, es un problema ya que no se ve bien si alguien sabe por favor que me diga como corregirlo.
Ojo Eso solo pasa cuando lo selecciono y no cuando lo escribo, Cuando lo escribo con el teclado todo normal aqui les dejo la foto para que se vea mejor.
1.-La primera es de cuanto escribo.
2.-La segunda foto es cuando lo selecciono con la flecha del teclado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los campos de entrada de texto suelen depender del navegador que les impone colores de fondo (por su cuenta) la solución es reemplazarlos por elementos div editables que pasen (en el evento onchange) su valor a campos ocultos de modo que los valores sean enviados cuando se haga submit al formulario. Yo me cansé de "luchar" sin éxito contra la "sabiduría" de los navegadores "inteligentes" y uso esa solución.

Comment: Esta bien hacerlo con Div.? Como validaria el usuario con php.?

Answer (score 0):

La solución  está en esta web

https://www.bufa.es/chrome-eliminar-background-amarillo-autocompletado-input/

En resumen si quieres cambiar el fondo es este código

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #fff inset;
}
```

para cambiar el color de texto este código

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
}
```

y sino  quieres que te autocomplete entonces este

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"></input>
```